# Python patch object, how to assert on calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, boto3

I'm trying to create some pytest unit tests on a custom ansible module. I'm trying to mock the boto3 client and just test the logic of the class.
I moved the initialization of boto into a class method so I can patch the class and replace it with a mock object.

Patch seems to be successful, the "_init_boto" method is returning a mock object.
But I can't figure out how to set the return value so that "describe_stacks(..)" returns a custom reponse, or assert on the calls on the mock.
Sample code:

cf_stack_exists.py:

```
import boto3
class CfStackExistsSimplified:

    def __init__(self, aws_profile) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.aws_profile = aws_profile
        self.boto_client = self._init_boto(aws_profile)

    def _init_boto(self):
        session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=self.aws_profile)
        return session.client('cloudformation')

    def exec(self):
        response = self.boto_client.describe_stacks(
            StackName=self.aws_profile
        )
        return response
```

test_myclass.py:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from cf_stack_exists import CfStackExistsSimplified

class TestCfStackExists:
    @patch.object(CfStackExistsSimplified, "_init_boto")
    def test_example(self, mock_init_boto):
        myclass = CfStackExistsSimplified(aws_profile="dev")
        response = myclass.exec()
        print(f"\n{mock_init_boto.mock_calls}\n")
        mock_init_boto.describe_stacks().assert_called()
```

When I run this it fails with the error:

```
...
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'mock' to have been called.
...
```

But the print statement is showing that it has been called?

```
[call('dev'), call().describe_stacks(StackName='dev')]
```

I really can't figure out how to assert this mock, tried lots of different assert commands. Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing parentheses after the mocked function object `describe_stacks`, you're calling the function again, getting the child `Mock` object returned by the mock call, not the mocked function object that has the call records.

To assert that a mocked function is called, call the `assert_called` method of the mocked function object itself.

Conversely, to access a child `Mock` object returned by a call to a `Mock` object, which is the case of `self.boto_client` since it is assigned with what's returned by calling `self._init_boto` (mocked as `mock_init_boto`), you should place parentheses after the parent `Mock` object.

Change:

```
mock_init_boto.describe_stacks().assert_called()
```

to:

```
mock_init_boto().describe_stacks.assert_called()
```